# How to filter or Modify the cells to only keep the text inside the speech marks

Tags: excel

I have a report from Office365 that displays Outlook rules forwards.
This is a report produced with Powerhshell so not very much polished.

The report shows in this format:

*"**peter.pan@wonder.com**" [EX:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=123123-peter.pan@wonde]*

I have the report on Excel but I cant figure out a way to clean up the text so to only keep the text inside the "**peter.pan@wonder.com**" also further ahead I will need to remove the " " but I am guessing that I will know how once I answer the first question.

Thanks, M

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula like:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(""" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(""" ",A1)-1))-1)
```

Or, before the report is in Excel, use a regex in a text editor or other software:

```
(?<=\").+(?=\")
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/ELcF2R/1/